# Assigning domains of variables automatically

Tags: assumptions

I want to find a feasible solution for mixed integer linear program. The first $t$ variables in the system are integers and other are reals.

The problem is that the no. of variables is more than hundred and so it is infeasible to assign domains individually.So, I want to know if there is any way to assign domains to variables in automated fashion.

Comment: `vars = Array[v, 120]; t = 40; $Assumptions = {Element[vars[[1 ;; t]], Integers], Element[vars[[t + 1 ;;]], Reals]};`

Comment: @BobHanlon But in LinearProgramming command, we don't specify variables. Is it possible to do this while using LinearProgramming command

Comment: As shown in the documentation, the fifth (optional) argument to [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html) is the domain specification(s). Try: `{ConstantArray[Integers, t], ConstantArray[Reals, n-t]}//Flatten`